# For loop in array reads 'remove'?

Tags: javascript

I just experienced the strangest thing, this is the code I'm actually using :

```
for (iter in data.List) {
    console.log(iter);
}
```

As you would expect, the log should give the number of each row (0, 1, 2...), instead it gives me this :

```
0
1
2
remove
```

**Knowing that my array only has 3 rows**

Did anybody ever encountred this ?

Comment: Show us the code that creates your list.

Comment: I'd recommand not using `for in` for arrays (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea )

Comment: I recommend to read the [MDN documentation about `for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). It tells you what the problem is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, the problem is that you are iterating through your array using a `for in` loop, which is not meant for iteratung through arrays. Its intent is to iterate through all properties of an object, and apparently there is a property called `remove` on your array.

For more details on why `for in` is a bad idea when it comes to arrays, see [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

As solution, I'd suggest to use an indexed `for` loop. This type of loop does not care about properties, hence you are fine. So it basically comes down to a very classical:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.List; i++) {
  console.log(data.List[i]);
}
```

*By the way: You should not uppercase anything in JavaScript, unless it's a constructor function. Hence it should be `data.list`.*

PS: A nice read when it comes to arrays and (mis-)using them, read [Fun with JavaScript Arrays](http://blog.mikota.cz/2013/06/fun-with-javascript-arrays.html), a quite good read.

Comment: It it helped, it would be great to mark this answer as answer :-)

Comment: Was waiting for the remaining time to mark an answer as the right answer to go off ;)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that is how `for..in` works in JavaScript. It enumerates over all **object** properties (not Array indexes). Simple solution: don't use `for..in` on Arrays, because that's not what it is for.